# Merge 2 datasets in directly below one another

Tags: r, join, merge

I have two datasets:

y:

| Country | month | New_Users | Returning_Users | line |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Angola | 2020-05-01 | 4 | 5 | clientline |
| Angola | 2020-06-01 | 5 | 6 | clientline |
| Ghana | 2020-06-01 | 10 | 15 | clientline |

x:

| Country | month | New_Users | Returning_Users | line |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Angola | 2020-05-01 | 1 | 8 | teamline |
| Angola | 2020-06-01 | 3 | 10 | teamline |
| Ghana | 2020-06-01 | 5 | 2 | teamline |

I want to merge them to return:

| Country | month | New_Users | Returning_Users | line |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Angola | 2020-05-01 | 4 | 5 | clientline |
| Angola | 2020-05-01 | 1 | 8 | teamline |
| Angola | 2020-06-01 | 5 | 6 | clientline |
| Angola | 2020-06-01 | 3 | 10 | teamline |
| Ghana | 2020-06-01 | 10 | 15 | clientline |
| Ghana | 2020-06-01 | 5 | 2 | teamline |

So it should merge by both country and line and y dataset should go below x dataset. Many of the merging methods I'm familiar with paste the data frames side by side instead of below one another.

Please help

Comment: you are looking for `rbind` or `dplyr::bind_rows`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `rbind` like this:

```
y <- data.frame(Country = c('Angola', 'Angola', 'Ghana'),
                month = c("2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-01"),
                New_Users = c(4,5,10),
                Returning_Users = c(5,6,15),
                line = c("clientline", "clientline", "clientline"))

x <- data.frame(Country = c('Angola', 'Angola', 'Ghana'),
                month = c("2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-01"),
                New_Users = c(1,3,5),
                Returning_Users = c(8,10,12),
                line = c("teamline", "teamline", "teamline"))

rbind(y,x)
```

Output:

```
  Country      month New_Users Returning_Users       line
1  Angola 2020-05-01         4               5 clientline
2  Angola 2020-06-01         5               6 clientline
3   Ghana 2020-06-01        10              15 clientline
4  Angola 2020-05-01         1               8   teamline
5  Angola 2020-06-01         3              10   teamline
6   Ghana 2020-06-01         5              12   teamline
```